# SPARK: Parse JSON and get the Parent Column name when child column name is set to true

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

Given a below data to pass:

```
{
    
    "properties": {
        "student_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "unique_id": true
        },
        "status": {
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "phone_number": {
            "type": "string",
            "ignore": true
        },
        "e_mail": {
            "type": "string",
            "ignore": true
        },
        "address": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "subjects": [
        "science",
        "english"
    ]
}
```

I am specifically looking for child columns "unique_id" and "ignore" and want to get the below output:

```
unique_id     | ignore                 |
----------------------------------------
[student_id]  | [phone_number, e_mail] |
```

There parent column names are always changing.
The child columns like "unique_id" and "ignore" can be present for any of the parent columns.
I would like to know the parent column name for which the "unique_id" and "ignore" is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use json4s to parse, and something like this works.

**imports & raw JSON**

```
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.{ JValue, JObject, JString, JBool, JField }
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse

val jsonString = "{\"properties\":{\"student_id\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"unique_id\":true},\"status\":{\"type\":\"boolean\"},\"name\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"phone_number\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"ignore\":true},\"e_mail\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"ignore\":true},\"address\":{\"type\":\"string\"}},\"subjects\":[\"science\",\"english\"]}"
```

**function to extract properties where `key == true`**

```
/** @param key where (key, true) exists for given properties, extract the property names
  * @param json raw String of JSON data
  */
def extractProperties(key: String, json: String): List[String] = {
  // parse String => JValue
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  val jval: JValue = parse(json)

  // extract "properties" from JSON
  val properties: List[JField] = jval match {
    case JObject(obj) => obj.filter(_._1 == "properties").head._2 match {
      case JObject(obj2) => obj2
      case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
    }
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
  }

 // extract property names where key == true
 properties
   .filter(property => property._2.asInstanceOf[JObject].obj contains (key,JBool(true)))
   .map(_._1)
}
```

**test it out**

```
val unique: List[String] = extractProperties("unique_id", jsonString)
// unique: List[String] = List(student_id)

val ignored: List[String] = extractProperties("ignore", jsonString)
// ignored: List[String] = List(phone_number, e_mail)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.
Plus I just converted it to a UDF and can directly call from Spark.
Thank you.